# es-lint rule for unnecessary async

Tags: typescript, jestjs, eslint, prettier

Is there an es-lint rule that will help catch unnecessary "asyncs"?

I want lint to yell or autocorrect from

```
it('true should be true', async () => {
expect(true).toEqual(true)
});
```

to

```
it('true should be true', () => {
expect(true).toEqual(true)
});
```

Comment: The rules are listed [here](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/), which is linked from the ESLint home page. Searching for `async` on that page finds the built-in rules related to `async` functions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the [`require-await`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/require-await) rule does this.

> **`require-await`**
>
> Disallows `async` functions which have no `await` expression.